# Making carousel, can't scroll after click function animates (JSFiddle link updated)

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Problem

I'm trying to make a carousel, so when a person clicks the back arrow the page `.animate` and scrolls back up to the previous chapter in the story. However, after this happens the page appear to get stuck and I can't scroll anymore. I'm wondering why this is happening?

### Update #2 - JSFiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/vzt2s4b5/4/

```
$(function(){

    /* -------------------------------------
    GLOBAL VARIABLES
    --------------------------------------*/

    var nav = 72.5;
    var splash = 750 + nav;
    var one = $(".one").offset().top - nav;
    var two = $(".two").offset().top - nav;
    var three = $(".three").offset().top - nav;
    var four = $(".four").offset().top - nav;
    var five = $(".five").offset().top - nav;

    /* -------------------------------------
    PROGRESS BAR
    --------------------------------------*/
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        var documentHeight = $(document).height();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();
        var scrollPercent = (scroll / (documentHeight - windowHeight)) * 100;
        var position = scrollPercent;
        $("progress").attr("value", position);

        /* -------------------------------------
        CHAPTER TEXT SWITCHING
        --------------------------------------*/
        if (scroll >= one && scroll <= two) {
            $(".title").html("Chapter 1");
        } else if (scroll >= two && scroll <= three) {
            $(".title").html("Chapter 2");
        } else if (scroll >= three && scroll <= four) {
            $(".title").html("Chapter 3");
        } else if (scroll >= four && scroll <= five) {
            $(".title").html("Chapter 4");
        } else if (scroll >= five) {
            $(".title").html("Chapter 5");
        } else {
            $(".title").html('It could have been me');
        };

        /* -------------------------------------
        ARROW CAROUSEL
        --------------------------------------*/

        $(".backward").click(function(){
            if (scroll >= two && scroll <= three) {
                $("body").animate({
                    scrollTop: $(".one").offset().top - splash
                }, 1000);
            } else {
                console.log("Backward");
                // $("html, body").animate({
                //  scrollTop: $(".two").offset().top
                // }, 1000);
            }

        });

        $(".forward").click(function(){
            console.log("Forward");
        });
    })
});
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Name of Website</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.ico"> -->
</head>
<body>

    <nav>
        <progress value="0" max="100"></progress><!-- /.progress -->
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="" class="bdnsun">
        </div><!-- .logo -->

        <div class="details">
            <p class="title">'It could have been me'</p>
            <span class="dot first">&#9679;</span>
            <span class="by">By</span>
            <span class="byline">Nancy MacDonald</span>
            <span class="dot second">&#9679;</span>
            <span class="time">Time to Read:</span>
            <span class="full">19 min</span>
        </div><!-- .details -->

        <div class="social">
            <a href=""></a>
            <a href=""></a>
            <a href=""></a>
        </div><!-- .social -->

        <div class="chapters">
            <div class="backward" id="target" title="Previous chapter"><i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-4x"></i></div><!-- /.backward -->
            <div class="forward" title="Next chapter"><i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-4x"></i></div><!-- /.forward -->
        </div><!-- .chapters -->
    </nav>

    <main>
        <div class="splash" id="top">
            <div class="teaser">
                <h1>'It could have been me'</h1>
                <p class="subhead">Thirteen women share their remarkable stories</p>
                <p class="byline-alt">Nancy MacDonald</p>
            </div><!-- .splash -->
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="chapter one">
                <p>Wolf kale chips stumptown fanny pack, vegan kogi asymmetrical. Locavore polaroid sustainable Blue Bottle, farm-to-table kogi plaid keytar Tumblr occupy gluten-free. Pitchfork shabby chic lo-fi flannel, bitters hella readymade. Ethical meggings master cleanse Schlitz mustache Blue Bottle, <span class="highlight">American Apparel</span> dreamcatcher vinyl Tumblr. Scenester try-hard Portland master cleanse. Skateboard tofu mumblecore, swag retro aesthetic kale chips American Apparel lo-fi normcore bespoke Helvetica synth. Tousled Brooklyn DIY, quinoa Etsy chambray umami.</p>

                <p>Meh literally freegan, church-key Tumblr sustainable mlkshk sriracha Pitchfork. Migas stumptown deep v lumbersexual. Cray roof party skateboard scenester hashtag, plaid distillery wayfarers banjo ethical artisan. Skateboard irony Portland deep v, cliche DIY Pinterest brunch Echo Park tilde Helvetica. Etsy stumptown chambray craft beer four loko brunch, twee mustache. Crucifix yr synth, irony mlkshk polaroid master cleanse iPhone mixtape twee direct trade keytar. Brooklyn Pinterest migas Portland gluten-free.</p>

                <blockquote>
                    <span class="quote">“</span>
                    Meh literally freegan, church-key Tumblr sustainable mlkshk sriracha Pitchfork. Migas stumptown deep v lumbersexual.
                </blockquote>

                <p>Blog cold-pressed vinyl Shoreditch organic put a bird on it. Salvia put a bird on it swag chillwave Bushwick, fanny pack stumptown art party selvage narwhal. Readymade distillery asymmetrical bespoke. Blue Bottle bitters tofu, Austin retro meh gentrify tattooed American Apparel Banksy. Try-hard whatever pug tousled DIY lomo. Marfa pop-up shabby chic messenger bag Intelligentsia. Kale chips gastropub viral, Helvetica forage disrupt mumblecore mlkshk Brooklyn vegan.</p>
            </div><!-- .chapter -->

            <div class="chapter two">
                <p>Chapter 2</p>
            </div><!-- .chapter -->

            <div class="chapter three">
                <p>Chapter 3</p>
            </div><!-- .chapter -->

            <div class="chapter four">
                <p>Chapter 4</p>
            </div><!-- .chapter -->

            <div class="chapter five">
                <p>Chapter 5</p>
            </div><!-- .chapter -->
        </div><!-- /.wrapper -->
    </main>

    <p class="more">Read More</p>

    <footer>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see a back arrow in your fiddle

Comment: your fiddle doesn't works as expected

Comment: @kmiyashiro In `index.html` the arrows should be in the top right corner. For whatever reason, the Font Awesome icons aren't showing up. But you can see them in the `<div class="backward">` and 'div class="forward">`

Comment: @Gepser I've removed the JSFiddle link, the code snippets provided were exactly the same and they showcase the same problem with the click function

Comment: @kmiyashiro You should see a back arrow now in the JSFiddle, and it was always there in the code snippet, under `index.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you create the click handlers inside your scroll handler.  That means that you can't click until you have scrolled once (when the handlers are created).  It also means that you will have created a new click handler for every time you scroll, so your click handling code gets called multiple times.  If you scrolled a lot then you would be getting stuck on all those calls.

Try pulling your handlers outside of the scroll method.

EDIT: Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brendaz/z03dm3pL/.  If chapters are given the class "chapter-" + chapterId, then you can refer to the current chapter by number.  This will get rid of all those if statements and neaten up your code:

```
function getCurrentChapter() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  var currentChapter = 1;
  while (currentChapter < NUM_CHAPTERS && 
         scroll>=Math.floor($(".chapter-"+(currentChapter+1)).offset().top-nav)) {
    currentChapter++;
  }
  return currentChapter;
}
```

Comment: @Andrew Nguyen - I forked your fiddle at [http://jsfiddle.net/brendaz/z03dm3pL/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/brendaz/z03dm3pL/1/) and moved the click handlers. If you look at the console you will see that the clicks are logged once for each click.  In your version they are logged hunderds of times for each click (which locks up the browser when they are clicked).

Comment: So now, the clicks are being logged once. But it no longer animates + scrolls to the correct chapter, only getting the `else` in my if/else statement

Comment: Move the declaration of scroll to the top of the file (and un-comment out the animate code) [http://jsfiddle.net/brendaz/z03dm3pL/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/brendaz/z03dm3pL/2/)

Comment: @Andrew Nguyen - I think it would be easier if you just keep track of the current chapter you are on, and then scrolled to the next one in the click handlers.

Comment: How should I rearrange my code to go about doing that?

Comment: @Andrew Nguyen - I have edited the answer to include a fiddle that illustrates.